# Reduce computation time of an SVM in Rapidminer

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, rapidminer

I am new to datamining and learning rapidminer. I need to implement an SVM for a project I am doing. However I am stuck since no matter the SVM It just runs for hours and days without knowing if it's close or not to finish.

I already removed  as many features possible using the Relieff filter and the Forward Selection wrapper and I am using the Linear Karnel which should be the quickest,the SVM has C of 0. The dataset itself as 3950 objects with 14 dimensions which I don't think it's a lot.

The only reason why I can think of for taking so much time is that I am using 10-cross validation, but even so It shouldn't take several days.
So my question are:

1-Seeing how I implemented my svm in the exemple bellow is there anything I can change to reduce the runtime?

2-In rapidminer is there any sort of way to see what's happening in the SVM to see why is it taking so long? Or at least to check in which iteration of the Cross Validation is?

The process itself using already the files post pre-processing( I can't share the dataset) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="all"/>
    <parameter key="logfile" value="D:\testexrff.xrff"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_xrff" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read XRFF (4)" width="90" x="45" y="165">
        <parameter key="data_file" value="C:\Users\glintthssig\Desktop\wrapper"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="x_validation" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation (11)" width="90" x="246" y="120">
        <parameter key="use_local_random_seed" value="true"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="remap_binominals" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Remap Binominals (5)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
            <parameter key="attribute" value="REINTERNAMENTO"/>
            <parameter key="negative_value" value="N"/>
            <parameter key="positive_value" value="S"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_numerical" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="94" name="Nominal to Numerical" width="90" x="45" y="165">
            <list key="comparison_groups"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="support_vector_machine_libsvm" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="SVM (2)" width="90" x="179" y="165">
            <parameter key="kernel_type" value="linear"/>
            <list key="class_weights"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="training" to_op="Remap Binominals (5)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Remap Binominals (5)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Numerical" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Nominal to Numerical" from_port="example set output" to_op="SVM (2)" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="SVM (2)" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="remap_binominals" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Remap Binominals (8)" width="90" x="45" y="165">
            <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
            <parameter key="attribute" value="REINTERNAMENTO"/>
            <parameter key="negative_value" value="N"/>
            <parameter key="positive_value" value="S"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_numerical" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="94" name="Nominal to Numerical (4)" width="90" x="179" y="165">
            <list key="comparison_groups"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model (11)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance (11)" width="90" x="212" y="30"/>
          <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model (11)" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Remap Binominals (8)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Remap Binominals (8)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Numerical (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Nominal to Numerical (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Apply Model (11)" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model (11)" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance (11)" to_port="labelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Performance (11)" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read XRFF (4)" from_port="output" to_op="Validation (11)" to_port="training"/>
      <connect from_op="Validation (11)" from_port="averagable 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: Consider using a profiler, and getting the rapidminer source code.

Answer (score 0):

The process looks fine.

There is a strange issue at the moment that can sometimes be fixed by the use of the `Materialize Data` operator. Place this somewhere inside the cross validation, I suggest immediately before the SVM operator.

It will either magically work or if not then we would have to resort to something else.

Comment: You could try a different svm operator to see if it works more quickly. To see where the cross validation is you can look at the status bar at the bottom. As an alternative you can use the `Log` operator. You can also use the `Sample` operator to reduce the data size so you could time how long it takes for 1%, 5%, 10% and so on to make an estimate for the full data set.

Comment: Weirdly enough I tried with Kernels which theoretically should have worst performances (RBF and Sigmoid) and I can get results under a hour. So I have no idea why for Linear and Polynomial it runs indefinitely, besides just assuming those Kernel just can't draw an hyperplane for this dataset. 
The svm operator I am using is the LibSVM which is one of the most used.

Comment: If you reduce the number of examples to a very small amount - say 1% - does it complete in a meaningful time?